# Restrict xsd enumeration to one value for all occurrences inside a document

Tags: xml, xsd

I would like to define an xsd schema which contains an enumeration. The enumeration's value should however be exclusive across the entire document. To illustrate this, consider the following schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:enumtest" targetNamespace="urn:enumtest" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:simpleType name="Country">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="CH"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="AT"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="DE"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:complexType name="Address">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Street" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="No" type="xs:integer"/>
            <xs:element name="Code" type="xs:integer"/>
            <xs:element name="Country" type="Country"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Items">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Address" type="Address" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="Document">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Items" type="Items"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The following two documents should pass validation because they each contain a unique value from the `Country` enumeration across the document (CH in first document, AT in second document):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:enumtest" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:enumtest enumtest.xsd">
    <Items>         
        <Address>
            <Street>Street1</Street>
            <No>1</No>
            <Code>1</Code>
            <Country>CH</Country>
            </Address>              
        <Address>
            <Street>Street2</Street>
            <No>2</No>
            <Code>2</Code>
            <Country>CH</Country>
        </Address>              
        <Address>
            <Street>Street3</Street>
            <No>3</No>
            <Code>3</Code>
            <Country>CH</Country>   
        </Address>              
    </Items>
</Document>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:enumtest" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:enumtest enumtest.xsd">
    <Items>         
        <Address>
            <Street>Street1</Street>
            <No>1</No>
            <Code>1</Code>
            <Country>AT</Country>
        </Address>              
        <Address>
            <Street>Street2</Street>
            <No>2</No>
            <Code>2</Code>
            <Country>AT</Country>
        </Address>              
        <Address>
            <Street>Street3</Street>
            <No>3</No>
            <Code>3</Code>
            <Country>AT</Country>   
        </Address>              
    </Items>
</Document>
```

The next document should be flagged as invalid since there is more than one value from the `Country` enumeration present in the document (CH and DE):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:enumtest" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:enumtest enumtest.xsd">
    <Items>         
        <Address>
            <Street>Street1</Street>
            <No>1</No>
            <Code>1</Code>
            <Country>CH</Country>
        </Address>              
        <Address>
            <Street>Street2</Street>
            <No>2</No>
            <Code>2</Code>
            <Country>CH</Country>
        </Address>              
        <Address>
            <Street>Street3</Street>
            <No>3</No>
            <Code>3</Code>
            <Country>DE</Country>
        </Address>              
    </Items>
</Document>
```

I already tried to experiment with a `<unique>` constraint, unfortunately without much success. Is there a way define such an exclusive enumeration per document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### XSD 1.0

You cannot constrain all `Country` elements to have the same one of several values simultaneously.  **Alternatives**:

- Your XSD could force all `Country` elements in a document to be a
  certain, preselected, value simultaneously via a `fixed` attribute.
- Your XML could (arguably should) be redesigned to factor the common
  `Country` value out of each `Address` and stored instead in a single,
  common location in the document, such as an attribute or child element
  of `Items` or `Document`.

### XSD 1.1

An `xsd:assertion` could express your constraint:

```
      <xs:assert test="count(distinct-values(en:Items/en:Address/en:Country)) = 1"/>
```

Here it is in the context of your complete XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:en="urn:enumtest" 
           targetNamespace="urn:enumtest" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" 
           vc:minVersion="1.1">
  <xs:simpleType name="Country">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="CH"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="AT"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="DE"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:complexType name="Address">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Street" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="No" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:element name="Code" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:element name="Country" type="en:Country"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="Items">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Address" type="en:Address" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="Document">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Items" type="en:Items"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:assert test="count(distinct-values(en:Items/en:Address/en:Country)) = 1"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the schema validator I'm working with doesn't support XSD 1.1 yet. But I might consider switching to an XSD 1.1 compliant product, therefore I'd appreciate it if you could give me a hint on how such an assertion could be implemented.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be what I'm looking for. Unfortunately I can't test your solution at the moment, since I don't have an XSD 1.1 compliant validator at hand.

Comment: You're welcome.   Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  (It works, you can be sure.  The only issue is whether you want to depend upon the less widely adopted XSD 1.1 standard.  If you have the ability to redesign the XML per the second bullet point under XSD 1.0, you should.)

Comment: Sadly I can't change the schema (which is actually far more complex than the simplified version in my question), since it has been designed by an external party. This effectively limits my choices to XSD 1.1. I've marked your answer as accepted. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It can obviously be done using assertions in XSD 1.1, but I don't think it can be done in XSD 1.0.